# Do pointers to items of a repeated GPB field stay valid if the field is modified?

Tags: c++, pointers, protocol-buffers

I'm writing a C++ app that uses Google Protocol Buffers to serialize data. Everything is working but I'm worried I'm overcomplicating some stuff.

Right now I have a GPB message called REPORT, inside of which is a repeated message field called RECORD. I have a C++ class called RecordManager, objects of which are responsible for managing individual RECORDs inside the REPORT. These RecordManagers are held in a std::vector. Periodically, I iterate through them and tell them to update their associated RECORD objects. I then serialize the entire REPORT to a file and carry on.

My issue is the manner in which I associate a RecordManager with a RECORD. Right now, when I need a new record, I add a new RECORD to the repeated field and construct a new RecordManager on the vector with an index to the new RECORD. Each time the RecordManager updates its RECORD, it uses the stored index to locate it on the repeated field and then do its work. If I want to remove a record, I have to remove the RecordManager from the vector, swap the last item on the RECORDs field with the one I'm deleting, trim the RECORDs field down by one, and then update the RecordManager for the swapped field with its new index. It's not really pretty.

What I would like to do is have each RecordManager simply hold a pointer to the RECORD on the repeated field, which would make things quite a bit cleaner. What I can't find (and the reason I'm doing it this way in the first place) is assurances anywhere in the GPB docs that these pointers will remain valid after allocations/deallocations. Running a few simple tests and quickly looking at the underlying RepeatedPtrField code, I seem to be safe, but I don't just want to depend on undocumented implementation. Is anyone familiar enough with the C++ GPB library to let me know if I'm safe?

I'm using GPB 2 right now but want it to be future-proof, if that makes a difference.

Thanks!

edit: Added some code I used to test:

First the message:

```
// test_message.proto
message RECORD{
   required int32 val = 1;
}

message REPORT{
   repeated RECORD record = 1;
}
```

And the source:

```
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "test_message.pb.h"

struct RecordManager{
   RECORD *my_record;
   RecordManager(RECORD * rec):my_record(rec){
     my_record->set_val(0);
   };
   void update(){
      my_record->set_val(my_record->val() + 1);
   }
};

int main (int argc, char ** argv){
   REPORT big_report;
   std::vector<RecordManager> managers;
   // Test using pointers while adding
   for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++){
      managers.push_back(RecordManager(big_report.add_record()));
      for (RecordManager manager : managers){
         manager.update();
      }
   }
   std::cout << big_report.DebugString() << std::endl;

   // Test using pointers after deleting from middle of repeated field
   big_report.mutable_record()->DeleteSubrange(5,1);
   managers.erase(managers.begin() + 5);
   for (RecordManager manager : managers){
      manager.update();
   }
   std::cout << big_report.DebugString() << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you show some code?

Comment: Good point - added one of my simple tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the author of proto2, and I would say that you're pretty safe. The `RepeatedPtrField` class is a public interface and a lot of code, especially inside Google, depends deeply on its internal workings. Some code out there actually shuffles sub-objects between messages to avoid allocations; that wouldn't really work if the class were not an array of pointers, and as long as it is an array of pointers it would be silly to use any implementation that invalidated pointers to sub-objects on modification.

That said, I no longer work on protobufs so I can't personally speak for what the team might do in the future.